# Headers in SignalR response

Tags: asp.net, signalr-hub, etag

I am writing an application using `SignalR` which acts as a push service of resources for clients. The service sends notifications to its clients regarding state change of resources at regular intervals. Sometimes, the resource state remains the same. In such cases I need a way to convey the same to clients without sending the same resource again. In a way, I want to implement something like `ETags` with `SignalR`. To do that I need to modify `SignalR` response headers (or I could use query string).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you are saying to pass the same state to clients (But with NOT MODIFIED kind of header) as well not to pass if it is same.

In such case you should actually not pass any message to the clients if the server hasn't anything new to give to the clients. This is how realtime applications are supposed to work.

Also instead of adding an overhead of extra HEADERS why don't you just send a simple actual signalR ping to the clients saying "Hey, nothing modified. Just chill!"